# Get latest 1 record from the each group by deviceid

Tags: sql-server, group-by

How to get latest record from each device?

Query tried

```
select * from Data 
where dname = 'abc'
group by did
order by timestamp desc
```

Sample data

```
sl  emei            mname dname did timestamp
66  868997036667    LB    abc   52  59.6 2019-09-06 14:51:21.0000000
67  868997036667    LB    abc   46  59.3 2019-09-06 15:51:21.0000000
68  868997036667    LB    abc   52  58.4 2019-09-06 16:51:21.0000000
69  868997036667    LB    abc   46  58.5 2019-09-06 17:51:21.0000000
```

Expected output

```
68  868997036667    LB    abc   52  58.4 2019-09-06 16:51:21.0000000
69  868997036667    LB    abc   46  58.5 2019-09-06 17:51:21.0000000
```

Comment: What is this `timestamp`: `59.6 2019-09-06 14:51:21.0000000`?  That does not appear to be a valid timestamp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `row_number()` with `partition`.

```
select * 
from (select sl, emei, mname, dname, timestamp, did
    , row_number() over (partition by did order by sl desc) as rn
    from Data where dname = 'abc') t1 
where t1.rn = 1
```